# PDF reader that smartly rearrange layout to fit on mobile screen for comfortable reading

Tags: pdf, mobile, pdf-viewer

Very often texts is too small and the comprimized solution is to zoom in and pan every single line.

I wish there is a mobile app that smartly resized the file for comfortable reading on small acreen.

Comment: Are you looking for a web based app, or iOS/Android app?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [qPDF Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qoppa.activities.viewer), or any other option from the answers here:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24522/is-there-a-way-to-adjust-the-size-of-the-text-when-reading-pdf-files

Another option would be the combination of [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) (convert PDF to ePub) and [FBReader](https://fbreader.org/) (displays ePub).

Comment: Can I use qPDF Viewer on a regular computer?  Reading down the first column, and then having to scroll up again to read the second column, drives me nuts.